# JSON RPC Client Go

Tags: json, go, client, rpc

I have a python server serving response through JSON-RPC. Here is a sample response from the server.

```
'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": "Peer 1: local 10.10.0.2  remote 10.10.0.1  state CONNECT\\nPeer 2: local 10.10.0.18  remote 10.10.0.17  state ESTABLISHED\\nPeer 3: local 10.10.0.10  remote 10.10.0.9  state ESTABLISHED", "id": "839732f9-cf36-46ff-8b9b-6120250d9ce5"}'
```

Here is the request I need to send to the server:

```
'{"method":"echo","jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["test_params"],"id":"839732f9-cf36-46ff-8b9b-6120250d9ce5"}'
```

Here is my client with go language:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
)
type Args struct {
    jsonrpc, id string
}

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "11.21.22.221:8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    args := Args{"2.0", "d87198f0-af92-49f8-9a7d-ab8bed5c4d17"}
    var reply string

    c := jsonrpc.NewClient(conn)

    err = c.Call("echo", args, &reply)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Response: %d", reply)
}
```

But, when I run this client, it is not sending anything in the params. Instead it is sending empty params like this:

```
'{"method":"echo","params":[{}],"id":0}\n
```

Can somebody help me telling what mistake I am making? I am a newbie to go language.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with jsonrpc and id being lowercase and thus private to the Args struct. If the API you are calling expects lowercase args, you can probably use struct tags to get around that

Comment: Thanks a lot. That tagging helped to certain extent in adding the params but, I need to add tags to the actual JSON itself like this -
How can I add jsonrpc and edit the id value 
    `  '{"method":"echo",**"jsonrpc":"2.0"**,"params":["test_params"],**"id":"839732f9-cf36-46ff-8b9b-6120250d9ce5"**}'  `

Comment: @rob74 or someone please tell me how can I edit the id value passed in the JSON RPC request or even add jsonrpc version along with the JSON (jsonrpc is required for 2.0) ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are doing is possible using the client as provided by go because the private `clientRequest` struct is currently defined as:

```
    type clientRequest struct {
        Method string         `json:"method"`
        Params [1]interface{} `json:"params"`
        Id     uint64         `json:"id"`
    }
```

What you pass into `Call` as `args` is stuck into `Params` and note how there is no "Version `json:"jsonrpc"`" inside of that struct.

AFAICT (which may be wrong, this is my first time reading through this code) you would need to implement your own [ClientCodec](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#ClientCodec). You could probably get away with copying most (all) of the parts out of the stdlib and add the field to the `clientRequest` above. ;-)