# Golang library (or code) needed for client JSON-RPC2.0 over websocket

Tags: json, go, websocket, client, json-rpc

I have to add

1. JSON-RPC2.0
2. over websockets, to my
3. Golang
4. Client process

to communicate with another server. Unfortunately, none of the requirements can be changed.

I have libs and example code that offer parts of the solution but I have been unable to put it all together.

I have looked at Ethereum (I cannot find a client example) [Ethereum rpc](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc#Server.WebsocketHandler)

A [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479360/json-rpc-client-go) that dials tcp.

This [dials TCP](https://ops.tips/gists/example-go-rpc-client-and-server/)

net.rpc [not 2.0, dials tcp](https://medium.com/@OmisNomis/creating-an-rpc-server-in-go-3a94797ab833)

over http [net/rpc and http](https://haisum.github.io/2015/10/13/rpc-jsonrpc-gorilla-example-in-golang/)

[This one](https://github.com/snaffi/booze) looked promising but I cannot make my client work.

```
type Params struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    h := NewRPCHandler()
    h.Register("some_handler", dummySuccessHandler)
    ts := http.Server{Handler: h}
    defer ts.Close()
    conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws_rpc", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error dialing %v", err)
    }

    client := jsonrpc.NewClient(conn.UnderlyingConn())

    par := &Params{"newuser"}
    req, err := json.Marshal(&par)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Bad marshal %#v", err)
    }
    var resp Result
    err = client.Call("some_handler", &req, &resp)
```

I tried with/without marshaling but I'm clutching at straws here.

Comment: If you are going to use Ethereum you might be better off tagging it with that.